# How do I find the records with the maximum value for a particular field in a group

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `graphs` table which has fields `name` and `version`.  Each time a record is inserted the version is `0` if name does not exist in the database and `max(version) + 1` otherwise. I'd like to get list of records with the highest version for each unique name.  The following code does this:

```
def self.latest_versions
   Graph.group(:name).maximum(:version).map{ |k,v|  find_by name: k, version: v}
end
```

but I wonder if there is a much faster way to do this using a scope that just chains active record relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
def self.latest_versions
  name_versions = Graph.group(:name).maximum(:version).map {|k,v| [k,v].join(';')}
  Graph.where("concat(name, ';', version) IN (?)", name_versions)
end
```

after get the `name, version` groups, convert it into an array, which concat the 2 column into 1, by query through the composed column, we only need another sql query, totally 2, much better than the existed one.

Comment: I do not think this will work, it just returns the record with the maximum version number over all graphs.  There are different types of graphs, distinguished by the :name field. Each type of graph has its own versioning, so the most recent graph with name 'line_plot', might have version 5, and the most recent graph with name 'bar_plot', might have version 7. Your code will only return version 7 of the 'bar_plot', but I need to return both version 7 or 'bar_plot' and version 5 of 'line_plot'

Comment: yep, understand now, sorry for the misunderstand.

Comment: @Obromios i have update the `answer`, you can check it.

Comment: This does look better, except for a typo, you just need to close with a right parenthesis at the end of the third line. I have accepted and upvoted it.  If you think the question and your answer could be useful to others please upvote the question.

Comment: Thanks, i have fix the typo broblem.